# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException on Capture Image using camera

Tags: android, android-camera, android-fileprovider

When I try to capture image using Camera I am getting an error,

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.test.driver, PID: 10512
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to find configured root that contains /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.test.driver/files/Pictures/JPEG_20180225_110337_390840290.jpg
android.support.v4.content.FileProvider$SimplePathStrategy.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:719)
android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:404)
```

Here is the code I am using,

**Manifest.xml**

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
</provider>
```

**file_paths.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="my_images" path="Android/data/com.test.driver/files/Pictures" />
</paths>
```

Also Here is the **Java code** to capture Image,

```
private void chooseImageFromCamera() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Globals.imageUri = android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity,  activity.getPackageName()+".provider", photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Globals.imageUri);
            activity.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, cameraRequestCode);
        }
    }
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = activity.getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    Globals.imagePath = image.getAbsolutePath();
    return image;
}
```

I also tried by changing this

```
Globals.imageUri = android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity,  activity.getPackageName()+".provider", photoFile);
```

to

```
Globals.imageUri = android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity,  "com.test.driver.provider", photoFile);
```

but it is also not working for me.

Also on the manifest file I tried by changing

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
```

to

```
android:authorities="com.test.driver.provider"
```

it is also not working for me.

Comment: Remove the Android part from your path. `path="data/com.test.driver/files/Pictures"`

Comment: <uses-permission
     android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"

Comment: @ReazMurshed  When I remove It showing an error "Namespace declaration never used"

Comment: change `path` value to `.`

Comment: @forqzy I already used these permissions for android.hardware.camera, android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Comment: @ShayanPourvatan Like, <external-path name="my_images" path="." />  right ??

Comment: @SHIDHIN.T.S yes

Comment: @ShayanPourvatan Thanks it works for me. Can you add it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must set path to `.` as current directory as following:

```
<external-path name="my_images" path="." />
```

It's good to see [commonsguy github](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-provider), if i add anything to it is redundant.